# Remote Administration IIS not working after sideloading to a device connected with fixed internet

Tags: iis, virtual-machine, win-universal-app

I must access some data from IIS by connecting my IIS to a virtual machine to avoid any further configuration.

The code is running well but after I  sideload  my app, it seems that my app can't reach my data anymore. For example, I've got a folder called `Video` in my shared folder and I just changed:

```
 static string adresse ="http://localhost"
```

into

```
static string adresse = "http://172.16.1.113";
```

the app can still run well when I am connected wireless to the network but when I use a   device connected with fixed internet I got a message saying it can't connect to the server

```
public static async Task<List<Uri>> GetMedia()
{
    try
    {

        List<Uri> target = new List<Uri>();
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var urlVideos = adresse + "/Videos";
        var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(urlVideos);
        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        string htmlString = result;

        document.LoadHtml(htmlString);

        var collection = document.DocumentNode.DescendantsAndSelf();

        foreach (HtmlNode link in collection)
        {
            if (link.Attributes.Contains("href") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(link.Attributes["href"].Value.Trim().Trim('/')))
            {
                target.Add(new Uri(adresse + "" + link.Attributes["href"].Value));
            }
        }

        return target;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        string errors = "Proxy.getMedia" + iLine.ToString();
        App.ProxyErrors = errors;
        throw;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I just had to go to app.manifest then capabilities 
 end enable private networks(Client and Server)